# What is fault tolerance in JMS?

Tags: jms

I came across the question that What is fault tolerance in JMS and how to handle it?
How you can get the messages which are not handled by the Consumer?

Please anybody can guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is a specification.

The exact details of fault tolerance would depend on the implementation.

Try looking at the ActiveMQ documentation, its an open source product that implements the JMS specification.